# Out of sequence logging by Elmah

Tags: logging, elmah

Has anyone encountered an issue with Elmah where it is not logging your errors sequentially?

Let's say i have a sequence of errors that I want to log, and one happens after another.

When I view the log from elmah.axd, they don't appear in the same sequence as it was logged.

Does anyone know why? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The details of the problems can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=258&thanks=258&ts=1319089300

Comment: no solution to this defect at this stage